# How to uninstall jamf software or prevent the daemon from running

Tags: macos-sierra

I've used my MacOS Sierra machine to access a client's intranet, but in order to gain access, I had to install [jamf](https://www.jamf.com/).

My current version of jamf is:

```
$ jamf -version
version=9.101.4-t1507816971
```

Today, there was a dialog on my computer insisting that I had to upgrade my OS, without an obvious way to dismiss it:

[image]

That's fine, I discovered in Activity Monitor that the `jamfHelper` was responsible and I could easily kill this.

**Edit:** The dialog is back after an hour or so after freezing the `jamf` daemon & `jamfAgent` processes.

*Aside: I'm running the latest security patched version of MacOS Sierra and don't have time for a clean build or to test an upgrade to High Sierra right now.*

**I just want out.** It's my machine, but has this software on it.

**How do I remove it without taking out a bunch of stuff which I still need?**

I'm concerned about running `sudo jamf -removeFramework` as I just *don't know what it does*.

Killing the `jamf*` precesses just launches new versions of them.

Here's what's  currently running after some recent `kill`s:

```
$ ps -ef | grep jamf
0 68775     1   0 11:34am ??         0:00.33 /usr/local/jamf/bin/jamf launchDaemon -enforceRestrictions -monitorNetworkStateChanges
0 68852     1   0 11:34am ??         0:00.08 /usr/local/jamf/bin/jamfAgent
```

501 68906 68221   0 11:35am ttys019    0:00.00 grep jamf

**Is there an easy way to prevent the jamf daemon from launching?**

Comment: Sounds good. How do I freeze the processes though? Is that ```kill -STOP ${PID}``` ?

Comment: No  the upgrade modal is back again. The daemon & jamfAgent are still frozen though, so I think something else is running

Comment: related: https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/27335/removing-jamf-from-my-personal-machine-without-rebuilding

Answer (score 1):

You enrolled your personal device in a client's management system? I would be very careful - many companies have policies about enrolling non-corporate owned devices in their MDMs. Some even have EULA language that states if you enroll a personal device in their MDM that they will consider the device their property. Unless there's a BYOD program, this is common.

If you remove the JAMF framework via `sudo jamf removeFramework` any profiles that were installed by the MDM will be uninstalled. Chances are that your access to the client network is controlled via profile. I would recommend contacting the client's Helpdesk, Mac support, or MDM support immediately. It's entirely possible they'll be willing to provide you with the means to get on the network without enrolling in the MDM system.

Or not, some places have strict controls over just who and what device can connect to their network. If this is required by your contract to have network access they should either accommodate your personal device or issue you a corporate device.

By unenrolling (removing the Framework) you won't be subject to the policies from their MDM. I'm still somewhat in shock that enrolling personal devices would ever be OK as there are usually policies that install software with corporate licenses.

Comment: There was little choice at the time - I needed access to something which required that. The "easy" answer was backup, wipe and start again. Not a quick win, but a clean slate is best.